# bc.info transactions with no timestamp

Tags: blockchain.info, timestamp

The last transaction in blocks 219882, 219888, and 219892 don't have a timestamp.  And by *last transaction* I mean the last transaction shown in the json file.

- [219882](https://blockchain.info/block-height/219882?format=json)
- [219888](https://blockchain.info/block-height/219888?format=json)
- [219892](https://blockchain.info/block-height/219892?format=json)

I find this to be a bit odd.  Does anyone know why this has occurred?

Answer (score 3):

There is no timestamp field in bitcoin transactions. BC.I timestamps the transaction when it comes to this service for a very first time. You should not use this value, because it can be quite incorrect/irrelevant.

I think that the last transactions in these blocks have not seen by BC.I in "wild" form. BC.I discovered them when they come within a block. So, it is a small bug on BC.I - it does not shows you timestamp for some txs.

Just live with it.

Comment: What do you mean by 'wild' form?

Comment: Wild = Not in a block